# Transfering files into XP Mode

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc

Is there an easy way to transfer files into an XP Mode virtual machine?  Used to you could install the integration features in VirtualPC and drag and drop files from host to guest.  However, I can't seem to get that to work.  Is there a "new" way that is provided?  I'd prefer not to have to setup a shared drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Windows 7 ( I don't know about the others), from your virtual PC you can access all your information that is on your regular PC. Virtual PC includes all your drives as network drives which you can access through explorer.

Answer (score -1):

Drag your host files into your desktop/the folder in which you would like to copy.Then everything is transferred in a short period of time.This works for me vice versa...

Comment: As stated in the question, this does not work.

Comment: anyway it works for me...may be you made sth wrong...